# Win32: edit control selection in dialog-based app

Tags: winapi, dialog, editcontrol

I have a dialog-based app with an edit-control in it. When I minimize / restore the app, everything's ok. But when I hide all the windows with holding down that Windows-logo-key and pressing "D" and then I restore the app, the edit-control selects everything inside it.

How to make it not to select the text on restore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to look at WM_GETDLGCODE and DLGC_HASSETSEL in MSDN.

Comment: I subclassed the edit control and cleared that DLGC_HASSETSEL bit. But I also read that it is somehow possible to do without subclassing? How to stop the "default container processing such
as dialog management code"?

Comment: "I subclassed the edit control and cleared that DLGC_HASSETSEL bit." - Do all work as supposed?
"But I also read that it is somehow possible to do without subclassing? How to stop the "default container processing such as dialog management code"?" - I do not know. You can try to watch messages for the edit control and dialog using Spy.